# Unable to identify element by selenium with ::after css

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

[Image looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfPYe.png)
I am unable to click on the drop down icon present in the image.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='support-servicedesk-navigator']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em")).click()
```

This does not work & represents the total box instead of the drop down icon.

HTML looks like this.

```
<td class="x-btn-mc">
<em id="ext-gen98" class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on">
<button id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">
<div class="mruIcon"/>
<span>Home</span>
</button>
::after
</em>
</td>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "where is your css"?
I was told by my dev that, ::after is a kind of css representation.
The <em>...</em> tag represents the entire image, but i want to click only the drop down icon present in that image. Has "::after" got to do any thing with this?

Comment: I know, it's not a good way.But i could get this working by writing as below.
    Actions act= new Actions(driver);
    act.moveByOffset(235, 85).click().perform();

Comment: Got the x,y coordinates using https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/